# How to Create Wallpaper Slider App (Android)

Tags: android

i am new in Android Programing

And i want to create a Image Sliding / Image Slide Show App, that contains some images.

There are three buttons in this app:

- Previous Button: that will navigate to previous image
- Set Wallpaper Button: that will set current showing image as
  wallpaper
- Next Button: that will navigate to next image

this app should show only provided images, should not show images from Phone / SD Card.

Comment: 1. Put images in assets folder so you can take from there instead of sdcard. 2. And try something for [gallery](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=gallery+androd+exa,ple&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=vFMYU4LaGOjV8geyn4HYCQ&gws_rd=cr#channel=fflb&q=gallery+android+example&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&spell=1)

Comment: you can get images from server , drawable folder or assets folder easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the following links hope it's work and you get him idea from it:

[Android how can i implement two on click on my image slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154571/android-how-can-i-implement-two-on-click-on-my-image-slider)

[android how to open slider images when onclick image and swipe with fingers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650528/android-how-to-open-slider-images-when-onclick-image-and-swipe-with-fingers)

Answer (score 0):

Make a screen with Gridview in the center of the screen and 3 buttons at the bottom. Save the images in Assets folder or Drawable . Here is a very useful link that will help you 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/